# Полупрозрачный текст на форме (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, текст

Мне необходимо вывести текст на форму (winforms), но текст должен быть полупрозрачным, с прозрачным фоном. Так же желательно чтобы текст находился под углом. Как это реализовать (если можно с примером)?

Comment: У меня есть впечатление, что достичь этого Вы сможете, если вместо WinForms приложения перейдёте на WPF - приложение. Во всяком случае, там настроек для оформления разных контролов гораздо больше, и расположение текста "под уголом" точно есть, это просто один из параметров контрола

Comment: @S.H. Да, я знаю что на WPF это проще. Но мне нужно на winform.

Comment: Winforms не поддерживает полупрозрачность. Эффекта можно достичь только самопальными костылями типа попиксельного смешивания цвета фона и цвета текста. Конечно вопрос не новый, поэтому можно поискать [готовые решения](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5034/How-to-implement-Alpha-blending). GDI+ вроде тоже что-то умеет по смешиванию цветов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Win Forms не поддерживает прозрачность, но вы можете использовать pictureBox, в нём создавать Graphics через pictureBox.CreateGraphics, и уже через него рисовать текст под углом на прозрачном фоне (Для этого есть отдельные методы, которые так же поддерживают угол наклона текста)